# Change size of UIImageView to fit different UIImages

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

So I have my UIImageView which is called `imgView`. Basically the user can add his own images to this view and save it again to his own gallery.

Because I don't know beforehand what the sizes the images from the User are the `imgView` should change it's size everytime to perfectly fit the image with aspectFit. If the image is small the `imgView` shrinks so it doesn't take up much space etc.

I have used this code in my `viewDidLoad` to achieve it but it doesn't do anything:

```
imgView.frame.size.width = imgView.image?.size.width
imgView.frame.size.height = imgView.image?.size.height
```

or

```
imgView.bounds.size = imgView.image?.size
```

What should I do differently?

Edit for alexburtnik's answer:

This is my code now:
[image]

In the Simulator:

[image]

I changed the background in my Image View to green. So right now it fills out the whole screen but it the view shouldn't be larger than the image itself.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: did you try setting the width and height of the imageview as the width and height of the image before adding the image to the imageview?

Comment: Your view isn't loaded yet. Can you try putting your code in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update width & height constraints:**

I assume you're using autolayout. If so, you should change constraints' `constant` values instead of setting frames manually. Here is an example:

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!    
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func setImage(image: UIImage) {
        imageView.image = image
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

        let imageAspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
        let screenAspectRatio = screenSize.width / screenSize.height

        if imageAspectRatio > screenAspectRatio {
            widthConstraint.constant = min(image.size.width, screenSize.width)
            heightConstraint.constant = widthConstraint.constant / imageAspectRatio
        }
        else {
            heightConstraint.constant = min(image.size.height, screenSize.height)
            widthConstraint.constant = heightConstraint.constant * imageAspectRatio
        }
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }        
}
```

Note, that you also have to drag outlets for `width` and `height` constraints from storyboard to your `viewController`

**Another solution without resizing UIImageView:**

If other UI elements don't rely on UIImageView's frame and the only thing you care about is image appearance, you can just set content mode to `Center` or `Top`/`Bottom`/`Right`/`Left` etc:

[image]

Just set UIImageView's background to clear color

Comment: Now sadly not I just updated my post. Right now the ImageView fills out the whole screen. But like I said it should be the same size as the Image inside.

Comment: @R3ptor The updated function works as expected. I'll let you know if I come up with a more elegant solution though.

Comment: yeah that's it thank you! I 'm just suprised because I was searching for something like this for days but could not find anything or was just bad with choosing search keywords. :D

Answer (score -3):

Just set the UIImageView Content Mode to Scale to Fit

[image: Scale To Fit]

Comment: there is no such thing like scale to fit